# How do you show just 2 posts on the home page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm currently having some trouble getting only 2 posts to show on the home page.

These are pulling through from an events page elsewhere on the site.

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">      

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <?php endwhile; // End of the loop. ?>

            <?php $whatson = new WP_Query(array(
            'post_type' => 'whats_on'     
                )); ?>
            <?php while($whatson->have_posts()) : $whatson->the_post(); ?>


    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5">
            <div class="thumbnail  col-centered"  style="width: 485px">

            <?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail') ?>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3><?php the_title() ?></h3>
                    <h4><small></small></h4>
                    <p><?php the_field('whats_on_description'); ?></p>
                </div><!--END caption-->

            </div><!--END thumbnail-->
        </div>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
</div><!--END row-->
```

Thanks in advance. I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Usually the number of posts is determined by the admin panel settings, but you could hard-code it in your `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$whatson = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => 'whats_on','posts_per_page' => 2   ));
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the 'post_per_page' parameter?

```
new WP_Query(array(
     'post_type' => 'whats_on',
     'post_per_page' => 2
));
```